# Wordpress Plugin jQuery Conflicts

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am developing a plugin, and i can not get  rid of jquery conflicts in the website, i want to include my own jquery and custom script in the plugin even if the theme uses already jquery, it is possible completly using again jquery in a different way that will affect only the plugin?

now i have this, but they get in conflicts with the theme jquery and scripts, how i cna separete the plugin jquery totally, i mean to be used only for the plugin?

```
    function il_style() {

    wp_register_script( 'il_admin_jquery_script', plugins_url( '/il_js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js' , __FILE__, true));
    wp_register_script( 'il_admin_jquery_forms_styler_script', plugins_url( '/il_js/jquery.formstyler.min.js' , __FILE__, true));
    wp_register_script( 'il_admin_custom_jquery_script', plugins_url( '/il_js/il.jquery.custom.js' , __FILE__, true));
    wp_register_script( 'il_custom_jquery_forms', plugins_url( '/il_js/il.jquery.forms.js' , __FILE__, true));
    wp_register_script( 'il_custom_jquery_captcha', plugins_url( '/il_js/QapTcha.jquery.js' , __FILE__, true));
    wp_register_script( 'il_custom_jquery_captcha_touch', plugins_url( '/il_js/jquery.ui.touch.js' , __FILE__, true));

    wp_enqueue_scripts('il_admin_jquery_script');
    wp_enqueue_scripts('il_admin_jquery_forms_styler_script');
    wp_enqueue_scripts('il_admin_custom_jquery_script');
    wp_enqueue_scripts('il_custom_jquery_forms');
    wp_enqueue_scripts('il_custom_jquery_captcha');
    wp_enqueue_scripts('il_custom_jquery_captcha_touch');
}
add_action( 'init', 'il_style' );
```

Comment: why not loading the default `jquery` form wordpress enqueue libraries? And make sure your custom scripts follow the wordpress jquery standard to prevent from conflicting.. https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/javascript/#indentation-and-line-breaks

Comment: It sounds like a bad practice to have plugin overriding the default, running jquery. Optimize your code so that it complies with the existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So are you saying that you want to be able to remove the users copy of jquery and use your own in your plugin?

If so, surely you should be checking if the user has jquery running on their site already and using that?

I'd be pretty pissed if a plugin was overriding my own copy.

Comment: i am totally agree, but i have specific stuff that are running only with jquery 1.11, and i can not get rid of the conflicts. What you can advice me in this situation? @jamespayne

Comment: Personally I would use an older version of jQuery and adapt my code to suit - If you really can't do without the very latest version you'll need to dequeue the standard version and enqueue your version, although it's going to be a bit of a minefield as not everyone uses jQuery in a standard way. For example I dequeue the built in jQuery and run it from the Google CDN for speed/latency reasons.